# Rails download: conflicting chdir during another chdir block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, chdir

I'm installing Ruby on Rails on Windows10, with help from a youtube tutorial

> How to Install Ruby on Rails on Windows10, author TubeMint

Ruby version is 2.6.5 Rails version 6.0.2.1
I've got an error for sqlite3. So I'm making copy/paste from git in a  gem file in my Sublime text editor

This was there and I commented it --> #gem 'sqlite3', '~>1.4'

And this I've pasted from git --> **gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"**
Now, when I run the command **bundle install**, in one point I've got following ERROR in Comand Prompt

> C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:183: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
>
> C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:191: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block

Since I'm just starting to learn ruby on rails I need someone who knows to fix this error for me.
I read all over the internet and youtube tutorials but I can't find the right solution.

Comment: Since this is a warning (i.e. not an error) happening outside of your code, there is probably nothing that you do about it. Are there any actual errors / things not working that you can see?

Comment: Webpacker configuration file not found C:/Users/..../Desktop/RubyOnRails/webApp/config/webpacker.yml Please run rails Webpacker:install error: No such file or directory @rb_sysopen - C:/Users/-----/Desktop/RubyOnRails/webApp/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)